# Automatically refresh JSP page and call Controller

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

In my dynamic web project, I need to call a method in my `Controller` to get some data from a database and then refresh my `JSP` page.

`Controller`

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request,response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request,response);
}

private void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if(request.getParameterMap().containsKey("action")) {
        action = request.getParameter("action");
    }

if(action.isEmpty()) {
    getAllOrders();
}
```

`getAllOrders` will grab some information from a `DataBase`, fill an `ArrayList` and then return to the `JSP` page where this info will be displayed.

Is there a proper way to make this call from the `JSP` page? I'm currently looking into whether I can use `AJAX` to achieve this.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Many folks would use AJAX for this.  You basically have servlets (since you are using JSP, I assume you also have servlets) that are designed to support AJAX-type requests, like returning JSON structures since JSON is easily handled by web client code, and every javascript library out there, like jQuery and Dojo, handle JSON.

Not knowing the specifics of your application, with AJAX, you can have the base page just be a plain HTML page, loading whatever javascript libraries/modules you need and then make AJAX calls to servlets to populate the page with dynamic data.

All of this assumes you require Javascript to be enabled in clients.  If you want to support clients with Javascript disabled, then you will have to use plain ol' HTML forms.